# Edit WAV file using C#

Tags: c#, wav, naudio

I want to cut parts from a WAV file, for example from part 00:05:00 to 00:06:15.

I tried with NAudio and only succeed trim from the beginning and end of the audio. Is there a way to trim from the middle of the audio while inputting the start and end points?

thanks!

Comment: In general or explicitly with use of NAudio?

Comment: in general will be great

Comment: In the docs of NAudio, that's the example: Trim a Wav File. What it is doing is setting a reader position to start position, then copy to a writer until an end position. So start and end are basically "not copied". What you need to do is: invert this. You need to _copy_ first n bytes, then ignore m bytes, then copy again to end.